# Hive sql rank over id

Tags: sql, hive, rank

I have this data. I want to aggregate it and put a row_number on the aggregated data.

```
| ID_1  | time| ID_2 |
a,        1,    36
a,        2,    36
a,        3,    45
a,        4,    65
b,        1,    75
b,        2,    35
b,        3,    35
b,        4,    76
```

The desired output would look something like this.

```
| ID_1  | ID_2 | Row_number |
a,        36,    1
a,        45,    2
a,        65,    3
b,        75,    1
b,        35,    2
b,        76,    3
```

My try is by using this code:

```
select
ID_1, ID_2,
row_number() over (partition by ID_1, ID_2 order by time desc) as Row_number
from table1
```

But that yield in:

```
| ID_1  | ID_2|  Row_number |
a,        36,    1
a,        36,    2
a,        45,    1
a,        65,    1
b,        75,    1
b,        35,    1
b,        35,    2
b,        76,    1
```

If I use group by at the end, I get some errors of time not being in group by.

Comment: i don't see any aggregation in the expected output. do you just want to remove duplicates per id1,id2 combination?

Comment: Well, I do not want to remove duplicates perse, since the time variable will not be a duplication. But I do want all unique combinations of ID_1 and ID_2, and then rank them by time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group by `ID_1,ID_2` first and then apply `row_number()` over it.

```
SELECT id_1,
       id_2,
       row_number()
         OVER (
           partition BY id_1
           ORDER BY time ) AS Row_number
FROM   (SELECT id_1,
               id_2,
               MAX(time) time
        FROM   table1
        GROUP  BY id_1,
                  id_2) b;
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9d9ac/19)